# How to display only .txt files with the name ScheduledJobs in them

Tags: grep, find

I have tried this:

```
find ~/ops_scripts -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "ScheduledJobs*"
```

but I'm not sure how to get only .txt files to display.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
find ~/ops_scripts -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*ScheduledJobs*.txt"
```